# ExtJS: init is a template method, what is a template method?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have just started to use the init method inside the Ext.app.Application and it states that it is a templated method, also same for launch and few others. The docs has a label attached with a grey background saying TEMPLATED.

What is a templated method? And how does it differ from other method?

Do I need to worry?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template method is a method that can be implemented on a derived class, like you want to do, and is then automatically called. No worries, it's something you will be doing a lot.

If you take a look at [the source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/source/Controller2.html#Ext-app-Controller-method-init) of the file you will see it is already there, but it's assigned with an empty function. The framework is calling that empty function. If you extend from a class which has template methods you can 'override' those methods. The framework is calling those methods in a certain order.

Piece of the source code of Ext.app.Controller:

```
/**
 * A template method that is called when your application boots. It is called before the
 * {@link Ext.app.Application Application}'s launch function is executed so gives a hook point
 * to run any code before your Viewport is created.
 *
 * @param {Ext.app.Application} application
 *
 * @template
 */
init: Ext.emptyFn,

/**
 * A template method like {@link #init}, but called after the viewport is created.
 * This is called after the {@link Ext.app.Application#launch launch} method of Application
 * is executed.
 *
 * @param {Ext.app.Application} application
 *
 * @template
 */
onLaunch: Ext.emptyFn,
```

Comment: Ah so a template method means you are able to override it with my own function ? So if its not a template method means you can't override it ? So creating a template method just means you call Ext.emptyFn ? So I can create my own template methods on a class that can be overriden in subclasses?

Comment: No, a template method means it's a method that always is called on the base class. So you don't have to implement a listener. If you don't 'override' it, the base class calls the empty function. If you implement it, your function in the derived class is called.

Methods on a derived class with the same name as methods on the base class are always overriding the base class method. This is OOP.